# Obenter y/o mostrar data de una fila de DataTable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código pero no funciona, no muestra el JSON de la información de cada registro que se muestra en la tabla al hacer click en el boto con clase "editar"

```
var listar = function() {
    var tablaPagos = $("#payments_table").DataTable({
  "language":{
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
  },
  ordering: false,
  "ajax":{
    "method":"POST",
            "url":"listar_pagos.php"
        },
        "columns":[
    {"data":"idPago"},
    {"data":"nombreCliente"},
    {"data":"numeroSubcredito"},
    {"data":"campanaProducto"},
    {"data":"tipoPago"},
    {"data":"fechaPago"},
    {"data":"montoPago"},
    {"data":"fechaRegistro"},
    {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary none-shadow'><i 
class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>"}
        ]
    });
obtener_data_editar("#payments_table tbody", table);
}
var obtener_data_editar = function(tbody, table) {
$(tbody).on("click", "button.editar", function(){
  console.log("ANTES");
  var data = table.row( $(this).parent("tr") ).data();
  console.log(data);
  console.log("DESPUES");
});
```

}

Mi problema es que la consola no muestra la información DATA me indica que

```
Uncaught TypeError: table.row is not a function
```

Estoy usando DATATABLE y jQuery en versión 3.5.1

Comment: Hola. ¿Aún necesitas ayuda con esta pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

```
Lo resolví de la siguiente manera
function getDataFromButton(button) {
  row = $(button).parents("tr");
  data = $("#payments_table").DataTable().row(row).data()
  return data;
}
function eliminarPago(button){
  data = getDataFromButton(button);
  console.log(data);
  //... Generas peticion AJAX (Esta la respuesta en una de mis otras preguntas)
}
```